# What API does the Magento Mobile Store native app use?

Tags: magento-1.7

I'm curious to know if the [Magento Native App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.magento.magento&hl=en) uses the REST API, Soap v1 or Soap v2?

How is it able to access data with regards to features like configurable products while I can't do the same using the Soap v2. For example, I can't get the configurable attributes for a configurable product, while the mobile app can do that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well....neither. The Native mobile app uses the module `Mage_XmlConnect` to get the needed data. It makes calls to the controllers in this module.

**A bit off topic:**
(almost) all the controllers inherit `Mage_XmlConnect_Controller_Action` so (almost) all calls pass through this action `Mage_XmlConnect_Controller_Action::preDispatch()`.
Most of the actions just load the layout and display it, so if you want to know how some data is rendered look in the blocks of this module.

Comment: FYI: Old article from Inchoo on this very subject. http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/develop-your-own-magento-mobile-application/

Comment: Thanks, I'm looking into it. If I had to build a native app or a mobile site that is remote and consumes magento's catalog, would you suggest that I pick the XmlConnect approach over using Soap?

Comment: I don't know if I'm the right person to answer this since I have no experience with a magento mobile app (and very little experience with mobile apps in general), but what I can say is that the SOAP service is veeeery slow. Before taking a decision, I would investigate how the XmlConnect module works, since 'mobile app' is the reason it was built for.

Comment: Is there no documentation on XmlConnect besides the inchoo url? I'm definitely trying to avoid SOAP for reasons beyond speed (like it lacking certain features) - for e.g this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17659446/accessing-configurable-product-attributes-via-magento-soap-v2

Comment: @Marius .. Do I need to use XmlConnect for developing app for my magento store ?

Comment: @PankajPareek I don't know. Maybe you can use that.

Comment: okay thanks. One more thing I am just reading this book ( https://www.packtpub.com/web-development/magento-mobile-how-instant ) but I am unable to find official Magento mobile extension on magento connect. Can you please help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

REST is the best to go for. While you are going to build a magento app with high-profile security, SOAP is the best one to serve your purpose.