# Magento’s XMLConnect basics guidelines please

Tags: magento-1.9, xml, mobile, application

I have investigated and found that it's possible to make android application via magento's XMLConnect extention. And as [inchoo](http://inchoo.net/magento/develop-your-own-magento-mobile-application/) said that it is coming pre-installed in magento since CE1.5 and later. And to find it one should go to Magento admin > Mobile > Manage Apps but i am not able to find such menu in magento admin, I am not that experienced in magento, but i have created 2 website from scratch and 1 website after buying a theme from themeforest, in my homework i have seen people are discussing [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16085352/why-does-xmlconnect-depend-on-so-many-modules) about modules and [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5741/what-api-does-the-magento-mobile-store-native-app-use) about API but no body is showing the path that how to get there. I have also searched the extension in magento connect. I have tried and downloaded the latest version of magento also but no luck. You must have understood my question up till now that how to get the "Mobile" menu in magento admin panel.

Answer (score 0):

edit app/etc/modules/Mage_XmlConnect.xml file, set  `<active>true</active>`